# jQuery Week Calendar without overlapping events

Tags: jquery, jquery-week-calendar

I am making a jquery calendar using the jQuery Week Calendar plugin (see https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar).
In my calendar, it should be impossible to schedule an event overlapping with a previously scheduled event. What is the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `allowCalEventOverlap: false` to the definition of the calendar:
For instance:

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar({
     timeslotsPerHour: 2,
     timeslotHeigh: 3,
     hourLine: true,
     allowCalEventOverlap: false,
     ....
});
```

*But I believe that the calendar does this by default.*

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/master/jquery.weekcalendar.js line 69